# Dojo menu bar selected state

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have problem with my menu bar items getting stack in the wrong stat. so I am trying manually to set there state depends on the mouse events. However something is not working I have tried:

```
dijit.byId("someDiv")._setStateClass(this.selected=false);
dijit.byId("someDiv")._set(“selected”, false);
dijit.byId("someDiv")._set(“active”, false);
```

url: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/ in dijit.MenuBarItem

Thanks

Comment: tried this too: _set("focused", false);

Comment: why are you using `_set()` instead of `set()`?

Comment: it does not make a difference.

Comment: can you try `focusChild()` instead of setting selected?
`menuBar.focusChild(menuBarItem)`

Comment: Thank you, it works to focus but how do you remove focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source for [_MenuBase](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/_MenuBase.js) and [MenuBar](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/MenuBar.js), you want to emulate the behavior they get from:

`menuBar.focusChild` to set the focus and then a combination of `closeChild()` and `onItemUnhover()` to remove it.

From `closeChild()` you can try

```
item._setSelected(false);
```

and from `onItemUnhover()` try

```
item._set("hovering", false);
```